# Find an example of series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Can someone show an example of series that a)$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n}$ is conditionally convergent such  $\forall_{n \in \mathbb{N}}{|a_n|<\frac{1}{n}}$
b)$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n}$ that diverges  such  $\forall_{n \in \mathbb{N}}{|a_n|<\frac{1}{n}}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For part (a), you can consider $a_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{n+1}$. Use the alternating series test and limit comparison test to show this is conditionally convergent. For part (b), you can consider $a_n = \frac{1}{n+1}$. Again, use the limit comparison test.

Answer (score 0):

$\textbf{Hint}$: For part (b), consider the series where $a_{\mathrm{n}}=\frac{1}{n+1}$.